# Send email attachment from php and upload ftp

Tags: php, ftp

Here I'm able to upload received file (file doesn't have known name, it was created with current date and time) into FTP. And in the same way I want to send that attachment as a mail.

The error I'm getting is (from the last statement in the below code):

> file open error.

I was not able to select the file received into php while sending mail. can someone tell me why and how?

```
$destDir = 'myweb.net/name/' .$dir;
 $workDir = 'tmpfiles';// define this as per local system

 // get temporary file name for the uploaded file
$tmpName = basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']);
$fileName = basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

// copy uploaded file into current directory
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'],$workDir."/".$tmpName)
 or die("Cannot move uploaded file to working directory");

// open connection
$conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die ("Cannot initiate connection to host");

// send access parameters
ftp_login($conn, 'abcd', 'saddad') or die("Cannot login");

// perform file upload
$upload = ftp_put($conn, $destDir."/".$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'],$workDir."/".$tmpName, FTP_BINARY);

// check upload status
// display message
if (!$upload) {
 echo "Cannot upload<br />\n";
} else {


 $to = $Remail;
 $subject = "This is subject";
 $message = "This is test message.";
// Open a file
 $file = fopen($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'], "r" );
 if( $file == false )
  {
 echo "Error in opening file";
 exit();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to open the ORIGINAL client-side filename, which has absolutely NO relationship to anything on your server. The only file that exists on your server is the one listed in `['tmp_name']`, which you've now moved to `$workdir`.

Your fopen should be

```
$file = fopen($workDir . '/' . $tmpName, 'r');
```

Plus, you have absolutely NO error handling on the user->webserver upload stuff, and are simply ASSUMING that uploads could never fail. Bad assumption.